# Changing value of <c:set jstl tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am using the following expression on my jsp

```
<c:set var="flag" value="false" />
```

I have a condition inside a for each loop where I might want to change this variable to true.  Is there a way to do this.  I've looked everywhere but unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the sample code you are looking for:

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${yourcondition}">
      <c:set var="flag" value="true" />
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
      <c:set var="flag" value="false" />  
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace this whole code by `<c:set var="flag" value="${yourcondition}" />`?

Answer (score 6):

why dont you just reuse the same code within your loop

```
<c:set var="flag" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do this as well

```
<c:set var="flag" value="${(yourcondition)? true : false}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

Syntax:

```
<c:set var="flag" value="${(condition)}" />
```

Ex:

```
<c:set var="flag" value="${(myVariable == "stackoverflow")}" />

<c:out value="${flag}" />     // true or false
```